# Temporarily pausing Compiler/GC threads in the JVM

Tags: c++, jvm, reverse-engineering

I am currently working on a c++ project that interacts with the JVM, I have no control over the JVM version or java application, while I can use JNI during runtime, it is unsafe with very tiny crash chance. I can safely use JNI during my init.

After debugging I have narrowed down the issue to the JVM setting the state of the current thread from _thread_in_Java to _thread_in_native when JNI is used (yes I am jumping from a Java function to c++ code), I am able to reproduce the crash by changing the state but not using JNI. My guess is that some sort of lock needs to be placed, but I have not been able to find it.

The crash seems to be caused due to some other thread (I'm thinking Compiler or GC) seeing that my thread's state is _thread_in_native, and doing some sort of unsafe operation.

I have tried using various variables in the JavaThread structure to set some sort of lock/flag but nothing worked.
My next approach was to use the windows API to Suspend all threads in the program except for my own, but this kills performance, I haven't found a way yet to map a JavaThread to a windows thread, so I'm not able to make a specific list of threads to suspend (with that list being just the compiler and GC threads).

My problem should be solvable if anyone could help me do one of the following:

1. Map JavaThreads to windows threads so I only suspend the Compiler/GC
2. Place a lock on my JavaThread or somewhere else so prevent other threads from working with it
3. Suspend the Compiler/GC threads some other way

Comment: How do you change JVM's thread state and why do you do that?

Comment: @apangin I am able to obtain a pointer to my current [JavaThread](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/runtime/javaThread.hpp#L244), after this I can access its variables using offsets, this is also how I obtain my JNIEnv*. The JVM changes the thread state when I use the JNIEnv, I can change it back manually but this only decreases the chance of a crash rather than fixing the problem properly.

Comment: Still not clear. Just don't mess with JVM internals, and it won't crash. Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try asking about your original problem instead.